# How to use metaprogramming to avoid a lot of typing by automatically generating objects?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

Recently, I had to write an After Effects plugin which had 110 "parameters". Each of these parameters had to be declared by three sort of functions: Creation, Check in, and Check out:

```
PF_ADD_FLOAT_SLIDERX(ID);
```

But for the parameter to check in and check out, and also, extract its value, I needed 110 `ParamDef` variables, and also, for example, a `PF_Fixed` variable to hold the value of `ParamDef`:

```
ParamDef var;
PF_Fixed val;
PF_CHECKOUT_PARAM(ID, &var);
val = var.u.ad.value;
PF_CHECKIN_PARAM(&var)
```

I know all those functions was inevitable, because that's how the SDK is created, and it's not designed for 110 parameters, however, my question is, after I was done with 330 functions, and 220 variables (I wrote a Python script to write them, in fact), I had to pass them to OpenGL. And I stupidly created map of `<string, float>s`. I could have done better, I could have used metaprogramming. But how? Instead of:

```
map["var"] = (float) val;
```

I could have done something more... Intuitive, perhaps. But what would that be? I am familiar with metaprogramming, I could have created a struct or a class, and generated an object for each GLSL uniform, and have each unifrom be a struct, but how could I have saved myself from typing?

In other words, is it possible for metaprogramming to automatically generate object and save yourself from tedium, instead of writing a Python script that does it, like I did??

Comment: I don't see why metaprogramming is needed here, can you show what you want? (even if it's only pseudo code)

Comment: Is `PF_ADD_FLOAT_SLIDERX` a macro? If all those look the same, why don't you use P99_FOR or BOOST_FOR macros? Can you give some more examples, as to identify the pattern of variables? `sort of functions` - can you give these "sort of function" declarations?

Comment: I think you are looking for reflection, that C++ doesn't have by itself. Some libraries allow to have some (with MACROs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have modern c++ with inline variables, you can do something like this at file scope for example:

```
inline ParamDef< your template parameters> param_1( constructor arguments);
inline ParamDef< your template parameters> param_2( constructor arguments);
```

My bet is you don't actually need template metaprogramming for what you are asking.